# React DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let me explain what my code does first. In `mn` there are some elements and whenever I hover the element inside it, it will add the `active` class (basically just change the text's color and leave the color there until I hover another element).

When I click the `img` which is just the logo, I expect it will remove the `active` class, but I don't know how to make the function, my problem is the `mn` is an array so I gotta iterate and make a condition or something that I don't really get the idea.

Can anyone help me? thanks before, appreciate any kinda helps

```
useEffect(() => {
    const mn = document.getElementsByClassName("mn");
    const logo = document.querySelector(".hd-left");
    const img = logo.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]; 

    Array.from(mn).forEach(
      (el) => {
        if (el.innerText === menuSelected.name) {
          el.classList.add("active");
        } else {
          el.classList.remove("active");
        }
      } 
    ); 
  });
```

Comment: direct manipulation of dom node is not recommended in react. How do you implement mn / log / img, are those coming from react rendering result?

Comment: Mutating the DOM that is controlled by react is a bad idea. React doesn't know about the changes and will override them if the components re-render, i.e. it will remove the classes you added. You can do the same things only using react state and callbacks.